# Is there any benefit to my rather quirky character sizing convention?

Tags: sql-server, binary, storage

I love things that are a power of 2.  I celebrated my 32nd birthday knowing it was the last time in 32 years I'd be able to claim that my age was a power of 2.  I'm obsessed.  It's like being some Z-list Batman villain, except without the colourful adventures and a face full of batarangs.

I ensure that all my `enum` values are powers of 2, if only for future bitwise operations, and I'm reasonably assured that there is some *purpose* (even if latent) for doing it.

Where I'm less sure, is in how I define the lengths of database fields.  Again, I can't help it.  Everything ends up being a power of 2.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
   ,Firstname varchar(64)
   ,Surname varchar(128)
)
```

Can any SQL super-boffins who know about the internals of how stuff is stored and retrieved tell me whether there is any benefit to my inexplicable obsession?  Is it more *efficient* to size character fields this way? Can anyone pop in with an *"actually, what you're doing works because ....."*?

I suspect I'm just getting crazier in my older age, but it'd be nice to know that there is some method to my madness.

Comment: Face facts, you're never going to be the subject of a movie like "a beautiful mind."  CTFO.  Also, does this annoy you:  ||||/

Comment: Specify varchar(max) and forget about sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relevant powers of two are `512` and `4096`, which is the default disk block size and memory page size respectively. If your total row-length crosses these boundaries, you **might** notice un-proportional jumps and dumps in performance if you look **very closely**. For example, if your row is 513 bytes long, you need to read twice as many blocks for a single row than for a row that is 512 bytes long.

The problem is calculating the proper row size, as the internal storage format is not very well documented.

Also, I do not know whether the SQL Server actually keeps the rows block aligned, so you might be out of luck there anyways.

Comment: disk block size is not exposed to applications and best practice is to format with 64k clusters for SQL Server because the minimum unit of IO is an extent or 64k. The 8k pages are stored that way too. 8k and 64k are the magic numbers, if any, in SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I'm your coworker and I'm reading your code, I don't have to use SVN blame to find out who wrote it.  That's kind of cool.  :)

Answer (score 0):

With varchar, you only stored the number of characters + 2 for length.

Generally, the maximum row size is 8060

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.bob (c1 char(3000), c2 char(3000), c31 char(3000))

Msg 1701, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Creating or altering table 'bob' failed because the minimum row size would be 9007, including 7 bytes of internal overhead. This exceeds the maximum allowable table row size of 8060 bytes.
```

The power of 2 stuff is frankly *irrational* and that isn't good in a programmer...